# Implementing OAuth 2.0 using WSO2 with custom token end-point

Tags: wso2

Is it possible to realize the following scenario using WSO2:

I have an existing API implementation (in form of a Spring Boot application) that needs to be protected. All access to the API should be authorized via OAuth 2 bearer tokens issued from a token endpoint. The Bearer tokens should be issued based on two different types of authorization:

1) An OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow, to an IdP-implementation I provide.
2) A bespoke Authentication Token generated by a 3rd party system (I will provide the code for validating such a token and identifying the scope etc. based on this)

So for both scenarios I need a token endpoint that can issue OAuth 2 Bearer tokens - based on either OpenID Connect Auth Code or on the bespoke token, respectively (with suitable code "hook-ins" provided me). Could this be WSO2 identity server?

It's particularly the last part I am unsure about - as far as I can tell, WSO2 Identity Server provides a token end-point. Maybe this could handle #1. But can I extend this so it can support scenario #2? Which WSO2 products would I be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager provides #1 OOTB. Both keygen and validation.

For #2, you need to do both keygen and validation with some custom code.

Validation: You can write a custom handler. See [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Writing+Custom+Handlers) for details.

Keygen: I can think of 2 approaches.

1) Expose your own service and change `_TokenAPI_.xml` to route to the correct token service based on something in the token request. Maybe a header?

2) Write the keygen in java as a custom class mediator and embed inside `_TokenAPI_.xml`. See [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Creating+Custom+Mediators) for details.